# Use os.scandir() to crawl a very large directory and send files to multiprocessing queue as discovered

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a very large directory and would like to recurse through, sending files to a multiprocessing queue as discovered for parallel processing.

```
PATH = "/mnt/large_directory"

def main():

#Initialize
print("Starting the scanner in root " + PATH)

with os.scandir(PATH) as it:
  for entry in it:
      if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
          print(entry.name)
          print(entry.path)
```

I have a function that I need to use to perform work on each file:

```
def doWork()
//Calculates md5 sum and other check sums
```

What's the right way to do this so that files are added to a multiprocessing queue as discovered when a worker thread becomes available?